# Операция блокирования прервана вызовом WSACancelBlockingCall

Tags: c#

Создаю свой сервер для чата по сети TCP, стартует сервер нормально. Но когда я его закрываю, получаю ошибку следующего вида на экране

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благодарю за помощь

Comment: В класс ServerListen надо добавить `: IDisposable` и реализовать его метод `Dispose()`. В методе слушателю надо дать команду на остановку прослушивания, а потом приравнять его к `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void ServerListen()
    {
        while (IsServerStarted)
        {
            try
            {
                var chatClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(ClientPart);
                clientThread.Start(chatClient);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                IsServerStarted = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

попробуй так, при ошибке получения клиента сервер будет останавливаться.

Comment: Способ по сути не плохой, однако не учтено - потоки, они могут продолжать что-то делать

Answer (score 1):

А чем вас, собственно, расстраивает это исключение? Суть этого исключения - в том что был вызван метод Close, который отменил вызов AcceptTcpClient - то есть сделал ровно то что нужно.

А значит, его вполне допустимо проигнорировать:

```
public void StopListening()
{
    this.listener.Stop();
}

private void ServerListen()
{           
    listener.Start(5);
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {               
            var chatClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(ClientPart);
            clientThread.Start(chatClient);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == 10004)
    {
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Обработка остальных ошибок
    }
}
```

Что же до клиентских сокетов - их проще всего закрыть через CancellationToken:

```
private readonly CancellationTokenSource ctsStop = new CancellationTokenSource();

public void StopListening()
{
    this.listener.Stop();
    ctsStop.Cancel();
    ctsStop.Dispose();
}

private void ClientPart(object chatClientObj)
{
    using (var chatClient = (TcpClient)chatClientObj)
    using (ctsStop.Token.Register(chatClient.Close))
    {
        try
        {
            // ...
        }
        catch (SocketException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == 10004)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Обработка остальных ошибок
        }
    }
}
```

Кстати, возможно их и не стоит закрывать сразу - иногда лучше дождаться завершения какой-нибудь важной операции (тут уже общего совета дать не могу - все зависит от требований к серверу):

```
private void ClientPart(object chatClientObj)
{
    using (var chatClient = (TcpClient)chatClientObj)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ctsStop.Token.Register(chatClient.Close))
            {
                НеважнаяОперацияКотораяИспользуетСокет();
            }

            // ...

            if (ctsStop.IsCancellationRequested) return;
            ВажнаяОперация();

            // ...

            ОперацияКотораяСамаУмеетПроверятьТокенОтмены(ctsStop.Token);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex) when (ex.ErrorCode == 10004)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Обработка остальных ошибок
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, пригодится

Answer (score 0):

Модифицировал, все нормально, UI поток работает корректно, не виснет

```
 public void StopLictening()
    {
        foreach (Thread itemThread in threadList)
        {
            itemThread.Abort();
        }

        this.listener.Stop();
        serverListeningThread.Abort();
    }

    private  void ServerListen()
    {           
        listener.Start(5);
        bool IsServerStarted = true;
        while (true)
        {               
            try
            {
                var chatClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(ClientPart);
                clientThread.Start(chatClient);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                IsServerStarted = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Все потоки абортим, которые задействованы

Comment: Abort - не лучший вариант, слишком уж он радикален

Comment: Ну да согласен возможно, так, но был одобрен вообщем-то как один из вариантов